# How to pass this TypeScript React component an optional prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm fairly new to TS and trying to understand how to pass optional props to this component that's a bit complex for me. I thought you could use a ? for the props that you want to be optional, but I'm getting the following error:

> A binding pattern parameter cannot be optional in an implementation signature.

How would I pass optional props to this component?

**With Optional Props**

```
export const BGVideo = React.memo(function BGVideo({ src, children, bgColor? }: any) {
  return (                                                          ^^^^^^^^
    <BackgroundVideoContainer>...some other stuff...
  )
});
```

**Original**

```
export const BGVideo = React.memo(function BGVideo({ src, children }: any) {
  return (
    <BackgroundVideoContainer>...some other stuff...
  )
});
```

Comment: You can use `?` in a type definition, but that's the right-hand side of the colon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Object where you are trying to add optional prop is a destructured props object and not the type of props object.

You can add type for props object as follows:

```
export const BGVideo = React.memo(function BGVideo({ src, children, bgColor }: {src: string, children: React.ReactNode, bgColor?: string}) {
  return (
    <BackgroundVideoContainer>...some other stuff...
  )
});
```

Or better extract the type in a interface or type for better readability:

```
interface BGVideoProps {
      src: string; 
      children: React.ReactNode; 
      bgColor?: string;
    }

export const BGVideo = React.memo(function BGVideo({ src, children, bgColor }: BGVideoProps) {   
  return (
        <BackgroundVideoContainer>...some other stuff...   ) 
});
```

Here, bgColor is a optional prop

Comment: lol, apparently I missed the question mark, thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

What you're thinking of is declaring an optional property of a type. For instance:

```
interface Props { bgColor?: string }
const a: Props = { bgColor: '#fff' } // valid
const b: Props = {}                  // valid
```

But the only type in your code here is `any`, which is not a good practice to use as it disables all type checking.

So what you want to do is delcare the *type* for your props, which includes the optional property:

```
interface Props {
    src: string,
    children: React.ReactNode
    bgColor?: string
}
```

Then use that type.

```
export function BGVideo({ src, children, bgColor }: Props) {
  return (
    <>...</>
  )
}
```

Now in that function, `bgColor` has the type `string | undefined`. A `string` if it was passed a value, or `undefined` if it was not passed a value.

[Working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOABRzAGc4BvUuXuNqGgBc-GFCoBzADQ8+aABbAANgBMilEcnQwAdFowA5CCqSzeAIwkBhCEugB+EWzGTSAX3JIAHpFhxMAK6UGMAQlHAAQgDiAGrAJhAAFJz8glJwCspqSJTpljZ2UHBuIiwQ7ACUXLJEMAFQ4YlmcAA8AHw6nS0A9G2yFe7kaGHOcDTOAIJwALyt0XEJqWjTAEQ63QBu8UgQOiAQGytw+bbQqwDEmFcrbeMwknAAjABMAMw989sQfcOUo3cRGZzWJfJardZbBJ7A43O4PF7vbqfBJtIA)

---

Lastly, `React.memo` really isn't necesary. You shouldn't really ever need to wrap a function component in this way. `React.memo` is more for values which you don't want to have to recompute.

Answer (score 0):

try that:

```
type Props = {
    src: string;
    bgColor?: string;
    children: React.ReactNode;
}
export const BGVideo = React.memo(function BGVideo({ src, children, bgColor }: Props) {
    return (
        <BackgroundVideoContainer>...some other stuff...
    )
});
```